# Is aws datapipeline service being deprecated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deprecation-warning, amazon-data-pipeline

When I navigate to aws datapipeline console it shows this banner,

> Please note that Data Pipeline service is in maintenance mode and we are not planning to expand the service to new regions. We plan to remove console access by 02/28/2023.

Will aws datapipeline service be gone in near future?

Comment: Probably. It basically was replaced by glue jobs.

Comment: No, AWS Data Pipeline is not being deprecated. It is expected to remain available in the near future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Maintenance Mode

Console access to the AWS Data Pipeline service will be removed on April 30, 2023. On this date, you will no longer be able to access AWS Data Pipeline though the console. You will continue to have access to AWS Data Pipeline through the command line interface and API. Please note that AWS Data Pipeline service is in maintenance mode and we are not planning to expand the service to new regions.

### Alternatives

For alternatives to AWS Data Pipeline please refer to

- [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue)
- [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions)
- [Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-workflows-for-apache-airflow)

For information about migrating from AWS Data Pipeline, please refer to the [AWS Data Pipeline migration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/migration).

### Contact

AWS will provide customers with at least 12 months notice before any service is deprecated.

If you have any questions or concerns, please reach out to [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/support).

Answer (score 1):

Console access to the AWS Data Pipeline service will be removed on April 30, 2023. On this date, you will no longer be able to access AWS Data Pipeline though the console. You will continue to have access to AWS Data Pipeline through the command line interface and API.

Please note that AWS Data Pipeline service is in maintenance mode and they are not planning to expand the service to new regions.